# Testing Spring Repository - keep failing to properly call EntityManager load and remove

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa

G'day dear stackers,

I am really struggling at the moment with a basic test class of a dummy DAO. Although I see that persist and find methods of the injected EntityManager finally triggers SQL queries, my assertions keep failing.

First, the test configuration I use:

```
<!-- test -->
<persistence-unit name="eSporxPersistenceTestUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>...CoalmineCanary</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

... together with the application context used by the tests:

```
<!-- data source definition -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- entity manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="eSporxPersistenceTestUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- transaction manager -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My DAO works with the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class CoalmineCanary {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String text;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

... and the very DAO:

```
@Repository
public class CoalmineCanaryRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void delete(CoalmineCanary entity) {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}

@Transactional
public CoalmineCanary findById(final int id) {
    return entityManager.find(CoalmineCanary.class, id);
}

@Transactional
public void save(CoalmineCanary entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}
}
```

My test class only consists in 2 very simple tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/META-INF/spring/testApplicationContext.xml")
public class CoalmineCanaryRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private CoalmineCanaryRepository canaryRepository;

private CoalmineCanary coalmineCanary;

@Before
public void setup() {
    coalmineCanary = new CoalmineCanary();
    coalmineCanary.setText("pokus");
    canaryRepository.save(coalmineCanary);
}

@Test
public void when_loaded_then_entity_is_retrieved() {
    CoalmineCanary managedCanary = canaryRepository.findById(1);
    assertThat(managedCanary).isNotNull();
    assertThat(managedCanary.getText()).isEqualTo("pokus");
}

@Test
public void when_removed_then_entity_not_retrievable() {
    CoalmineCanary managedCanary = canaryRepository.findById(1);
    assertThat(managedCanary).isNotNull();
    canaryRepository.delete(managedCanary);
    CoalmineCanary canary = canaryRepository.findById(1);
    assertThat(canary).isNull();
}
}
```

Here is the console output when I run the tests:

```
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:39 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager retrieveTestExecutionListeners
INFO: @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class tv.esporx.framework.CoalmineCanaryRepositoryTest]: using defaults.
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:39 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/testApplicationContext.xml]
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:39 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@c4fe76: startup date [Sat Feb 25 14:41:39 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:40 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from file [/usr/local/projects/esporx/esporx-webapp/target/test-classes/META-INF/spring/datasource.properties]
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:40 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from file [/usr/local/projects/esporx/esporx-webapp/target/classes/META-INF/spring/datasource.properties]
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5eb489: defining beans [coalmineCanaryRepository,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,validator,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:40 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'eSporxPersistenceTestUnit'
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: eSporxPersistenceTestUnit
    ...]
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:41 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: esporx.coalmine_canary
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, text]
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: insert into coalmine_canary (text) values (?)
Hibernate: select coalmineca0_.id as id0_0_, coalmineca0_.text as text0_0_ from coalmine_canary coalmineca0_ where coalmineca0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into coalmine_canary (text) values (?)
Hibernate: select coalmineca0_.id as id0_0_, coalmineca0_.text as text0_0_ from coalmine_canary coalmineca0_ where coalmineca0_.id=?
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@c4fe76: startup date [Sat Feb 25 14:41:39 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5eb489: defining beans [coalmineCanaryRepository,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,validator,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 25, 2012 2:41:42 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean destroy
INFO: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'eSporxPersistenceTestUnit'
```

What happens now is that findById(1) always returns null.
I've been trying to change many things but still fail to make the tests pass...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Rolf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code written by you are fine, but the tests needs a bit of tuning,

```
private CoalmineCanary coalmineCanary;

@Before
public void setup() {
    coalmineCanary = new CoalmineCanary();
    coalmineCanary.setText("pokus");
    coalmineCanary = canaryRepository.save(coalmineCanary);

    if(coalmineCanary.getId() == 0){
       fail("Could not insert the Canary!");
    }
}

@Test
public void when_loaded_then_entity_is_retrieved() {
    CoalmineCanary managedCanary = canaryRepository.findById(coalmineCanary.getId());
    assertThat(managedCanary).isNotNull();
    assertThat(managedCanary.getText()).isEqualTo("pokus");
}
```

Your tests could be failing because **there is no guarantee that the id of the objects willl be 1**. When the entities are saved, hibernate updates the `id` with the value from the DB and returns the object back. If you want to use that you should return that for the caller method.

Here in your test method instead of the hard coded id you should be using the id of the saved bean so that the tests can pass. Also, Let the tests fail if the `id` was not set in the `setup()` method.

Comment: you're absolutely right... I wrongly thought the H2 database instance was re-created from scratch at the each new class tests execution, which is obviously not the case...

in the meantime, I also created a named query to find canaries by text, and found that more than 50 canaries were already stored...